# Save Session in SMTP protocol and JavaMail api

Tags: java, smtp, gmail-api, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I develop a Java application that sends emails on behalf of the user.

To avoid saving the user's password, I want to store the Mail Session.
However, I see that in Java's Mail api of the SMTP protocol, the implementation authenticate on each message sent!

Is it just an **implementation** or is it declared to be so in **SMTP protocol**?

My code:

I am using JavaMail API to start an SMTP Session and send an email, as follows:

```
//Set up headers
String from,to...

//Set up authentication
  Properties props = new Properties();  
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
      }  
    });  

//Set up message
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
...

//Send message
  Transport.send(message);
```

While in Transport.send(message) (Inside JavaMail api), there is the following implementation:

```
try{
  this.Connect()
  this.SendMessage(message)
  this.CloseConnection()
}
```

Can I use the implementation of transport.SendMessage(message) without transport.CloseConnection()?
Thus I will save the session and continue using it.

Will SMTP support it? How much time the sessions will be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems to work ok.
Instead of using

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Use:

```
Transport transport = message.getTransport(address);
try{
   transport.connect();
}catch (Exception e){
   //already connected
}
transport.sendMessage(message);
```